# PHP - How can i display all the images on a selection list

Tags: php

I want to count all the images in a specific folder(i already did it), and i want to put those images into a selection list

How can i adapt this and put all the images into a selection list?

The user must select an image, and this image must be saved into a table.

```
<html>
<body>

  <?php

   $files = glob("imagens/*.*");

   for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)


  {

  $image = $files[$i];

  print $image ."<br />";
  echo '

  <img height="30" width="30" src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
   }

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, try to save Image paths in DB. Don/t save images in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplist way to use a select box for your images. As for saving the image, that poses a couple of other issues (db connection, form, etc.). Try a solution then if you have problems come back with what you have done.

```
<?php
$files = glob("imagens/*.*");

echo '<select name="file">';

foreach($files as $file){
    echo '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```